# How to get Map<String, String[]> data with @RequestParam in controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a page with many questions, and they can have multiple answers.

It's look like this, for every question:

```
<div th:each="answer: ${question.answers}">
    <input th:type="${question.type == T(test_system.entity.QuestionType).SINGLE ? 'radio' : 'checkbox'}"
           type="radio" th:name="${question.id}" th:value="${answer.id}"/>
    [[${answer.text}]]
</div>
```

I want to get a `Map<String, String[]>` in controller, which processes this request. (key is id of question, values is answers for this question)

I have this code in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/work/{id}/finish", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendTestAnswers(@PathVariable final long id, @RequestParam final Map<String, String[]> data, final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) {
    ...
}
```

But in data I see `Map<String, String>`, with only one anwer for every question.

Also in request.getParameterMap() I see `Map<String, String[]>` with all values that I need.

How can I bind arguments to get prepared object with all data that I need?
I don't want to work with HttpServletRequest directly.

Comment: *I don't want to work with HttpServletRequest directly*: why, since it provides exactly what you need?

Comment: @JBNizet because there are another, extra parameters like csrf, in it. And it needs additional code to process

Comment: I don't see how your desired usage of RequestParam would avoid having the other params in your map? How would Spring decide which parameters to put in the map and which one not to put in it? Sometimes, you need to write code.

Comment: csrf it is a special parameter, I didn't create any field in my form for it. It created automatically. 
And Spring know about it and I don't see this parameter in @RequestParam data now. I have only questions in it, but only with one answer for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should give MultiValueMap a try: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html

It is better suited for these kind of data.

Comment: It's work, thank you. But it's also contains additional fields like csrf.